# Entity Framework Core upgrade from 2.1.4 to 5.0.5 or 6.0.* migration add error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, casting, entity-framework-migrations

Have confirmed I have not made any db changes or model changes before the upgrade from ef core 2.1.4 to latests version 5 or 6. Yet I seems to now have this error during add migration.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'.
```

I use the command

```
dotnet ef migrations -v add ChangeNameExample -o Models/Db/Migrations
```

I checked all the db table columns match the models i.e. bigint sql column is a long type in the model. The file I'm primarily looking at is the DbContext class. With ef migration changes I can't see where else to look.

Gone over the breaking changes upgrade notes and nothing about a casting int to long issue.

Will try a fresh project and see if any modelBuilder property changes are required.

Anyone else came across this?

Edit:

full stack trace by using these settings in the OnConfiguration().

```
optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
optionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors();
```

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'.
   at lambda_method34(Closure , IUpdateEntry )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.SimplePrincipalKeyValueFactory`1.CreateFromCurrentValues(IUpdateEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.IUpdateEntry.set_EntityState(EntityState value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.TrackData(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDataOperations(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'.
```

Comment: Post your code and the *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the debugger's exception popup. The problem is in the code. EF Core 2 reached end of life *several* years ago. It had a *lot* of quirks that covered up missing features. Even migrating to EF Core 3 would throw errors as warnings became errors once the missing features were implemented

Comment: The full exception text includes the location of the error and a stack trace that shows the chain of calls that led to it. This can help you identify the method in your own code that resulted in that error. It's possible that older migration scripts use the wrong type, or your code may be using constructs that are no longer invalid. I can't stress enough how limited EF Core 2 was, or how many bugs were covered up. In a *lot* of cases, client-side evaluation was used when EF Core couldn't translate a LINQ query to SQL with just a runtime warning. You could end up with an entire table in memory

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos looks like I will have to recreate this from ground up.